# Google Apps Script - Unable to query property from JSON data

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-api, dialogflow-es, chatbot

dialogflow sends the following:

```
{
  "responseId": "XXX-YYY-ZZZ",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "random text",
    "parameters": {
      "command": "do it"
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Sorry, can't understand it.",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Sorry, can't understand it."
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/xxx-vyyy/agent/sessions/xxx-yyy-zzz/contexts/__system_counters__",
        "parameters": {
          "no-input": 0,
          "no-match": 0,
          "command": "do it",
          "command.original": "do it"
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/xxx-vyyy/agent/sessions/xxx-yyy-zzz",
      "displayName": "testCommands"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "payload": {}
  },
  "session": "projects/xxx-vyyy/agent/sessions/xxx-yyy-zzz"
}
TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;parameters&#39; of undefined (line 5, file &quot;this-file&quot;)
```

and the goal is to query the `command` field. This is the current code:

```
function doPost(e) {
  //EXTRACTION
  var dialogflow = e.postData.contents;      
  var desiredField = dialogflow.queryResult.parameters.command;
}
```

but then this error thrown:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;parameters&#39; of undefined (line 4, file &quot;this-file&quot;)
```

I tried `JSON.stringify(e)` and `e.postData.contents`, but still not working.
Documentation on `doPost()` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web
and `WebhookRequest` sent by dialogflow https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook#webhook_request

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At `doPost(e)`, `e.postData.contents` is not parsed as JSON object. I think that your error message is due to this. So how about the following modification using `JSON.parse()`?

#### Modified script:

```
function doPost(e) {
  //EXTRACTION
  var dialogflow = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);  // Modified
  var desiredField = dialogflow.queryResult.parameters.command;
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)